# Why I cant assign a function like this

Tags: javascript

Why I can't make this in javascript:

```
var log = console.log;
log(123);
```

And how to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, the value of `this` depends on how a function is called.

Inside `log()`, `this` is `undefined` in strict mode or the default object otherwise (that's `window` in a browser).

Inside `console.log()`, `this` is `console`.

The `log` function, presumably, depends on having access to the `console` object.

You can write a wrapper function instead:

```
function log() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

In [sufficiently modern browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind), you can generate that function using `bind`.

```
var log = console.log.bind(console);
```